# Mendeley JS SDK Client Credentials Flow authorization

Tags: javascript, sdk, authorization, spfx, mendeley

I am building a SPFX SharePoint online webpart using the Mendeley Javascript SDK and trying the Client Credentials Flow authorization. I get the CORS error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.mendeley.com/oauth/token' from origin 'https://xyz.sharepoint.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. */

```
private clientCredentialsFlow() {
    var sdk = mendeley;
    var api = sdk({
        authFlow: sdk.Auth.clientCredentialsFlow({
        clientId: 1234,
        clientSecret: 'abcdefghijk',
        redirectUri: 'https://xyz.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx'
      })
    });
```